# Mosquitto TLS/SSL SSL3_READ_BYTES: ssl handshake failure, Error: Success and sslv3 alert

Tags: ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I tried following the guide shown by [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-tls-7.html) but once I launch the mosquitto

```
mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf
```

which defines port, location of ca.crt, server.crt, server.key

then I followed similar step using the same CA file, to sign the client key and certificate.

Then launched client

```
mosquitto_pub -p [port] -h localhost --cafile [ca.crt filepath] -t "hello" -m "hello world"
```

when I do it like this without key and certificate I get

```
Error: Success
```

but when I do it with key and certificate

```
mosquitto_pub -p [port] -h localhost --cafile [ca.crt filepath] --cert [client.crt path] --key [client1.key path] t "hello" -m "hello world"
```

I get

```
Error:Success
```

On the server side I See the following errors

```
... routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES: sslv3 alert certificate unknown
... routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES: ssl handshake failure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran openssl commands to verify CA approves of both generated certificates, and it did.

It turns out, when entering the detail of the certificate, i mistake the common name section's purpose. After I set it to the ip address of the server, it all worked well

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I tried to subscribe like this:

```
mosquitto_sub -h ip_address -p 8883 -t topic --cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt -d.
```

Replace ip_addres with your ip address that you wrote when you created certificate. In your question, you wrote localhost. If you replace it with ip address it will be work.